# Display select2 generated inputfields only with CakePHP 2.8.x form helper

Tags: php, jquery, forms, cakephp, jquery-select2

UPDATE:

Already found out what the issue was. Had to add `'multiple' => 'multiple'` to the input array from `this->Form->input`. When i added that line, the input field from Cake will be replaced by **Select2**.

I'm using **CakePHP 2.8.x** in combination with the **Select2** plugin in order to get multiple select boxes, like [this](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple).

Here's my issue:

I have created an input field with the CakePHP form helper:

```
                $sizes = array('s' => 'Small', 'm' => 'Medium', 'l' => 'Large');
                echo $this->Form->input('size',
                    array(
                        'options' => $sizes,
                        'class' => 'form-control haai'
                    )
                );
```

Cake creates the id TransferSize for me, that i can use for the Select2 plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Select2
        $("#TransferSize").select2({
            placeholder: "Select your emailaddresses"
        })
    });
</script>
```

What happens when i do this, is that **Select2** generates extra input fields within **Cake**'s input field.

Is there a way to hide the input field that **CakePHP** produces and display the input field that the **select2** plugin generates in the hidden **CakePHP** input field? Or is there a better solution that any of you know?

Help will be greatly appreciated ofcourse! :)

Comment: #TransferSize is form ID?

Comment: #TransferSize is ID from the generated CakePHP inputfield

Answer (score 0):

All you've to do is put your script before the `</body>` tag just like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Select2
        $("#TransferSize").select2({
            placeholder: "Select your emailaddresses"
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
```